# Django runserver won't run because of bootstrap error message

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

When I try to run my server in Django it is not able to find my app `track` that I just created:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'track'`

I got the same message for the app I was working on previously. I also get error messages relating to bootstrap, the last one being this:

`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'`

I started noticing this once I removed the bootstrap configurations from another app I was working on. I just downloaded bootstrap and know very little about it, especially how it could stop a Django server from running and not recognizing my app.

Any ideas???

Comment: Have you put your `track` app in your `settings.py` file ? Also, I don't think bootstrap is the problem here but how your project is set up (even though I don't have a lot of info to work with). You should add more info about your project such as the place where import bootstrap and your app.

Comment: I think that you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already created an app which is 'track' by this command: python manage.py startapp track, don't forget to add it to the installed apps on the settings.py.
example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app1',
    'track',
    'app2'
]
```

Also don't forget the add "," after each app, last one doesn't matter.

Comment: It does not matter if the last one has a comma after since it is a list in Python...